# Understanding Privileges in Sudoers File

Tags: sudo

I'm trying to make sense of the `sudo` documentation on [the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo). On it, it uses the two examples below. However I don't understand the difference between them. Why has the group sudo got (`ALL:ALL`) as compared to the (`ALL`) option for root? What does each part of the command do.

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#Default rule for root.
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Eplanation for `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`:-**

- `%sudo` - the **group** (named `sudo`) allowed to use `sudo`.
- 1<sup>st</sup> `ALL` means to allow `sudo` from any terminal, or from any host (on any machine)
- `(ALL:ALL)` indicates command can be run as **`(User:Group)`**
- Last `All` means all commands can be executed

**Explanation for `root ALL=(ALL) ALL`**

- `root` - the **user** (root) allowed to do everything on any machine as any user

---

Explanation for `(ALL:ALL)`: (Run as `(User:Group)`)

- 1<sup>st</sup> "ALL" indicates that the user (in case of `root`) or group members (in case of `%admin`) can run commands **as all users**
- 2<sup>nd</sup> "ALL" indicates that user (i.e `root`) or group members (i.e. of `%admin`) can run commands **as all groups.**

If only `(ALL)` is used then it doesn't allow to run as another group whereas `(ALL:ALL)` says ***Run as All users and All groups***.

Comment: So I assume that there is no point in actually having (ALL:ALL) as it does the same as putting (ALL)?

Comment: @johnsmith as my answer shows, `ALL:ALL` is not the same as just `ALL`.

Comment: @johnsmith have you read last line?

Comment: I find your answer confusing. I thought that the root settings are nothing to do with sudo. So I'm not sure why you refer to sudo in your explination of the root command.

Comment: Unless the ALL command is also used as an alias to do something with sudo, which would be super confusing, but hilarious

Comment: I have figured it out. The line you reference below was the one confusing me
"root - the user (root) allowed to use sudo". I think you were using the sudo group as an example of being ALLOWED to actually use any group, as opposed to root having access to the sudo group specifically.

Comment: @johnsmith FYI:- `sudoers` file only controls what sudo invocations are possible. `root` never needs `sudo` to do anything but if `root` user execute command with (invoking) `sudo` then `root ALL=(ALL) ALL`  is for it's convenience. ([visit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99008/66803) [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99009/66803))

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `ALL:ALL` and `ALL` in `RunAs` is the combinations of user and group that can be used. For example:

```
# sudo -u muru -g git id
Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/id' as muru:git on muru-laptop.
# sudo -u muru -g muru id
uid=1000(muru) gid=1000(muru) groups=1000(muru),10(wheel),21(locate),102(polkitd),190(systemd-journal)
$ sudo -u muru -g git id
uid=1000(muru) gid=997(git) groups=997(git),10(wheel),21(locate),102(polkitd),190(systemd-journal),1000(muru)
$ id    
uid=1000(muru) gid=1000(muru) groups=1000(muru),10(wheel),21(locate),102(polkitd),190(systemd-journal)
```

The first two commands were run as `root`, the third and fourth under my normal user who has `(ALL:ALL)`.

With only `ALL`, `-g` can only be used to specify the primary group of the user - which is no better than not specifying `-g` at all. `ALL:ALL` can be used to give any combination of valid users and groups.

I don't know why this (artificial) restriction is in place.

Comment: Oh man. I am a new linux user, this is way over my head.

Comment: @johnsmith <shrug> I doubt you'd have to actually use a combination this way. Most cases require just the user, or nothing at all.